# PowerShell output gets all messed up

Tags: powershell

I am running a `mingw32-make` command directly in PowerShell to build a C project.

However, the output sometimes get completely messed up, eg part of one line is inserted into another line etc. Sometimes this makes reading the output impossible.

It seems that the output is consistent between two runs, ie for certain project state it will always produce the same messed up output.

I tried dumping the output to a txt file as `mingw32-make > log.txt`. I get clear output in the text file, but all error reports are missing! It just says "Compilation error" without actual error report.

Any ideas how can this be fixed?

Comment: you are probably seeing output via more than one stream. they can get out of sequence ... especially the `*-Host` stream and the success stream. try redirecting ALL the streams to your file.

Comment: That did the trick. I was redirecting only `stdout` to a file, but it did not occur to me that compilation errors are reported in `stderr` stream. I can clearly read all errors now in a file! This is the command: `mingw32-make 2>&1 > log.txt` - this redirects stream 2 to stream 1 (`stderr` to `stdout`), and dumps all to file `log.txt`. Thanks for good idea! Feel free to post your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: kool! glad to help [*grin*] ... and i added an Answer that seems to cover it. if you think it otta be modified, please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you could consider including the command that I used to dump both streams to a file? Just to have everything in one place.

Comment: done as you requested ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you describe sounds like `mingw32-make` is sending to more than one stream. mingling output like that is similar to what happens when you mix `Write-Host` and `Write-Output` calls. the 1st goes [more or less] directly to the host, but the 2nd goes to the success stream and *then* to the host.

the simplest solution is likely to just redirect all the streams to your file, OR to combine the ones you want & `Tee-Object` the result to the screen and your file. [*grin*]

take a look at `Get-Help about_Redirection` for details.

i see that you used `mingw32-make 2>&1 > log.txt`. i could not specify any particular stream since i have no way to test that particular utility. i suspect i would have gone with `mingw32-make *> log.txt` to redirect all the streams. your pattern is better in that it avoids overdoing things.